# Http response status 415: AWS SNS request subscription error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-sns

I'm trying to follow the aws guide for setting up AWS SNS in my django project.
I have already setup my AWS topic and subscriber and I've set the endpoint at `api/v1/sns/`

Here is the view that is related to the url `api/v1/sns/`

```
class AwsSNSHandler(APIView):

    parser_classes = [JSONParser]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        subject = 'Amazon SNS Subscription'
        message = json.dumps(request.data)
        send_mail_from = 'someone@mail.com'
        recipients = ['example@mail.com']
        send_mail(subject, message, send_mail_from, recipients)
        return __success__("Receieved message", {})
```

But this request is never completed successfully whenever I request a subscription. The backend returns a 415 Http Status.

What could be wrong?

UPDATE: AWS SNS sends the request in plaintext format. Is this causing problems?? If yes, how do I fix it?

Comment: seems like the error is  somewhere from your application, as there is no such status code in SNS errors list https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/CommonErrors.html

Comment: Yeah ik it's from the server but why am I  getting it I have no idea

Comment: better to show `send_mail`

Comment: I guess its because aws sends payload in plaintext format and there's something im missing